# Nodemailer: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm setting nodemailer for sending emails. All the emails are sent properly but there is an error I can't solve. The error message is:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

This is my code:

```
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
   console.log(mailOptions);
  })
  .then((ok) => {
    return ok;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.name = "SequelizeValidationError") {
      let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
      res.status(422).send(response);
    } else {
      let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
      res.status(500).send(response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Using `callbacks()` and `then()` together are not right. Use one or the other (`then()` only when the returning value would be a full-fledged promise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add the async keyword in the  when try used then it should be use promise the should be used key

```
async function sendASNICMAIL() {

 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    console.log(mailOptions);
}).then((ok) => {
    return ok;
}).catch((error) => {
    if (error.name = "SequelizeValidationError") {
        let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
        res
            .status(422)
            .send(response);
    } else {
        let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
        res
            .status(500)
            .send(response);
    }
});
```

}
try to this and tell me if work or not in commit
]

Comment: Yes, the async keword works fine. Thanks a lot for your answer!!

Comment: How is the async keyword helping if he is not using await?

Comment: there are to way to write async  function   but the await maybe has written or used key  then and catch async function f() {
  return 1;
}

f().then(alert); // 1

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a callback to `transporter.sendMail()` so it won't return a promise. That's why you cannot use `.then()`.

From their documentation:

> If callback argument is not set then the method returns a Promise object. Nodemailer itself does not use Promises internally but it wraps the return into a Promise for convenience.

What you should be doing:

```js
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
  .then((ok) => {
    return ok;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.name = "SequelizeValidationError") {
      let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
      res.status(422).send(response);
    } else {
      let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
      res.status(500).send(response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works fine, but Nodemailer send the email twice. How is this possible?

Comment: Could you add the content of mailOptions to your question? Are you sure you are not calling sendMail twice?

Answer (score 0):

You've told nodemailer that you don't want a Promise by supplying a callback. You can either

1. Remove the callback and use a promise:

   ```
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
   .then((ok) => {
     console.log(mailOptions);
     return ok;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.log(mailOptions);
     if (error.name = "SequelizeValidationError") {
       let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
       res.status(422).send(response);
     } else {
       let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
       res.status(500).send(response);
     }
   });
   ```

   or
2. Use a callback instead:

   ```
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, ok) => {
       console.log(mailOptions);
       if (error) {
         if (error.name = "SequelizeValidationError") {
           let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
           res.status(422).send(response);
         } else {
           let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
           res.status(500).send(response);
         }
       }
       else {
         // Do whatever you want with "ok"
       }
   });
   ```